# Successful install of `pip install -e` but all imports are flagged as errors in PyCharm

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

A package I developed named `my_package` that worked fine for over a year when installing using `pip install -e`, lately started to flag an error when importing it. The installation is successful and everything works fine at runtime but `import my_package` is flagged as `No module named my_package` in PyCharm. What can be the reason?

Comment: Did you wait to the index reload? Also, you can go to file -> repair IDE to restore indexes

Comment: Please read [mre] and make it possible to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Note: you may have setup a different python environment in PyCharm. Check on properties (and then Project XXX).

Comment: @fran-arenas I waited for it to finish index and repair did not help :(. @karl-knechtel I use -e to install the package from a local directory i.e. the directory where `my_package` has all of its source files (not .whl). `my_package` is in the correct directory. Im sure of the location because the project that uses `my_package` works fine in run time.

Comment: I misread the problem description; I thought perhaps you were expecting to grab the package named `foo` from PyPI, but instead attempting to install from a local `foo` project directory (which would either not be found or not contain the package you set up on PyPI previously).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [fairly long-standing bug in PyCharm](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-976). One workaround is to mark your package as "Sources" manually in the "Project Structure" of your project's settings.

Comment: How can I do that if the package is in a different directory from the my project?

Comment: You can add a new "Content Root" in the right pane of the "Project Structure" settings.